# Can we close questions that put most code in an image?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes I just see questions that post code in an image like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667315). As we know, code in images is not very helpful to other visitors. Honestly, even the question is valid and we can help OP to extract the code from the image, I think it is more meaningful to spend the time on other users instead of having typing exercises, and I don't want to give wrong messages to OP that somebody would solve the problem by reading codes on the images!

Can we flag to close these types of questions? If so, what should be the close reason?

Comment: We can, as they lack an MCVE.

Comment: That particular question is too broad since it is asking for free labour - someone to do the work for them, other reasons include its unclear what is being asked and sometimes "why isn't this working"

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate of the linked question. Also, does anyone know if there is an "official" response on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends. If the question is well asked, well described and the image is the only problem, I would drop a comment, giving OP a chance to edit their question and replace the image with actual code. Sometimes, if the image doesn't contain tens of lines, I edit the code by myself and leave a comment so OP can learn for future not to do that again.

However, if the question is unclear, too broad or a duplicate, I would VTC for the relevant reason and would still ask OP to edit their post and replace the image with actualy code.

Comment: We can still CV it. An closed question that gets edited will get pushed into the reopen queue.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's true. Sometimes I just like to give OP chance to edit their question, if they don't respond, then I VTC.

Comment: You should vote to close along with your comment. It will have the same effect as giving the OP a chance to edit their question, considering how long it takes the average question to accumulate 5 close votes. But if the OP *doesn't* ever edit their question, your close vote has just put it that much further on the road to closure. Unless you are a moderator with insta-close powers, *there is no reason to delay voting to close*.