# Propose new reasons to close questions with insufficient information

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I suggest adding more specific reasons than the current **too broad** when closing questions to help new users better understand why their questions are getting closed. Similar to the **Off-topic** sub-reasons.

I'm editing this question with the comment I wrote to @Keving that fail to see how that would help new users any more than the existing reasons (Basically it will make them feel more welcome):

> Allowing to close questions with more detailed reason might also reduce rude and insulting comments from other uses that know the rules - They are being rude because they have seen 1000 questions like that before and can't explain the rules over and over again and keep a nice tone (It's frustrating). Being able to just close the question with more accurate reason will replace the need to also leave a rude comment that eventually is just trying to explain why that question is low-quality.

The feed of question on my account on SO is filtered by the `CSS` and `HTML` tags (and other tags). These tags are related to questions about styling issues and often attract new users asking questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271402/how-to-align-the-label-for-the-md-switch-in-angular-material-design)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180936/clicking-on-link-should-open-in-content-page#comment63793259_38180936) where the OP is usually asking about some general vague issue and includes an image of that problem. There are also questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255198/how-can-i-remove-the-padding-from-my-header#comment63931607_38255198) with little more than a link to a website where the problem happens.

I see this type of question A LOT (almost every time I visit StackOverflow), and I always VTC the question, but I don't feel that the closing reasons available in the closing tab describe well enough what's wrong with the question:

1. The questions are not necessarily off-topic the way described in the sub Off-Topic reasons:

   - I don't want to close it with the **"why isn't this code working?"** option  because I have yet to see the actual code.
   - The user doesn't ask for book/tutorials recommendations.
   - The problem might be reproducible, but there is no code to determine that (Making the **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** irrelevant).
2. The question is indeed too broad but not because *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.* as explain in the **too broad** option.
3. The question is also unclear of-course but just because it's missing important details, that would have made the question clear enough to answer. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159441/how-can-i-add-pop-art-effct-over-image-in-jquery-and-php) is a question worthy of the **unclear** option.

I've searched for related questions asked about closing questions that are mainly based on images/links-only. I found this question: 
[Can we close questions that put most codes in an image?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326495/can-we-close-questions-that-put-most-codes-in-an-image) closed as duplicate of another discussion created 2 years ago.

I chose to ask this, despite the similar questions because I'm suggesting we replace the general **too broad** with more case specific reasons (Similar to the **Off-topic because...** option):

- Questions including only images to describe the issue must also be supported by code.
- Questions including only a link to an external website must include reproduction steps and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the bug in the question body.
- Code requests posing as questions. All questions must include code and/or detailed description of the attempts the OP tried so far.
- The question lacks sufficient information. The user needs to add details to narrow it down (Similar to the current reason).

I hope that narrowing the **too broad** reason to be more case specific will help new users to better understand why their question was closed and what they need to change in order to get the question reopened again.

Comment: so, if it's unclear. No matter WHY... "unclear", is appropriate as a close reason. What would that new close reason bring that "unclear" can't do?

Comment: @Patrice I describe the reason at the bottom: **I hope that narrowing the too broad reason to be more case specific will help new users to better understand why their question got closed and what they need to change in order to get the question reopen again.**

Comment: You can always use comments to give more guidance to the author of the question, if you feel that it is needed.

Comment: "Why isn't this code working" means the OP is asking why their code/app/website isn't working. It doesn't mean "the code they've put in their question". So don't feel bad about closing such questions with that close reason.

Comment: @Louis But it's almost always because of the same reason. and there is alread reasons to closing question - I think they can be improved instead of posting the same comment over and over again

Comment: @TylerH It's for the new users that don't know the rules of SO. It seems that lots of people are not reading the rules before asking questions

Comment: @AlonEitan Sorry, are you saying your feature request is for new users that don't know the rules? Or are you trying to tell me that the "Why isn't this code working" CV reason for new users?

Comment: None of those questions you referenced are too broad... they're all either unclear or off topic for not showing the code that wasn't working.

Comment: @TylerH The first option I think - My suggestion is to make to `too broad` more specific to allow new users to edit the question once it got closed (That usually the one asking those very low quality questions because they don't know the rules for asking questions). I think that leaving the same "Welcome to SO!" comments is not good enough

Comment: I fail to see how that would help new users any more than the existing reasons. They can still edit and their questions and nominate for reopening with the existing reasons.

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't like writing the same comment over and over either but for the sake of the site and for the sake of the OP an early comment is *much* better than a late closure notification. It is often the case when I close a question that needs a MCVE, for instance, I'm also going to leave a comment saying so. In my view, the fact that eventually the OP will learn the close reason does not lessen the desirability of providing feedback as fast as possible.

Comment: @KevinB Allowing to close questions with more detailed reason might also reduce rude and insulting comments from other uses that know the rules  - They are being rude because they have seen 1000 questions like that before and can't explain the rules over and over again and keep a nice tone (It's frustrating). Being able to just close the question with more accurate reason will replace the need to also leave a rude comment that eventually is just trying to explain why this question is low-quality.

Comment: Don't we then get at risk of having to have so many CV reasons as to make the CV dialog extremely hard to navigate?

Comment: The generic problem with proposals like this is that it assumes that SO users are complete idjuts.  They are not, they are very skilled in omitting enough information to prevent their question getting closed as a duplicate.  We optimize for that behavior.

Answer (score 13):

> I don't want to close it with the "why isn't this code working?" option because I have yet to see the actual code.

And yet, is that not exactly the issue? If they're asking about a code problem, and they haven't provided any code, then it should be closed until the code is provided. Not unless you can make a diagnosis from the description alone.

Your suggested close reasons are just variations on the same theme: lack of an MCVE. And we have a close reason for that. One which has a proper link that describes what they need to provide.

Comment: What about users asking us to write the code for them (I bet you've seen questions like that before), or questions asking us to debug problems in websites without any actual description related to the relevant code causing it. My opinion remain that the **too broad** reason is just too broad and doesn't cover enough cases that I often see on SO. I still think that new users will benefit from knowing why their question is closed and will help them to learn how to ask better from now on.  I think lots of user treat those links similar to the terms of service (I don't bother myself to read them)

Comment: case 1: it depends, is it "how do i do x", or "write x for me"/"here is my assignment". case 2: that's not too broad, it's off topic.

Comment: The second case is definitely the MCVE issue.... You need code, expected result, and actual results... So "here is my website, how do i fix X?" is no MCVE.... And the "write for me" is too broad.... Quite explicitely actually.

Comment: @AlonEitan: "*My opinion remain that the too broad reason is just too broad and doesn't cover enough cases that I often see on SO.*" ... that's self-contradictory. Being broad is what *allows* it to cover those cases. Well, except for the cases covered by code problems. The thing is, there's no fixing a "give me teh cod3z!" question, so what we tell such people is irrelevant. That question, and nothing like it, is wanted here. Questions about code that is not presented is a *fixable* problem.

Comment: Thank you for that last comment