# What type of closure should we vote for questions containing code images?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There are many questions that contain code images instead of code in textual code-block form.

I want to vote to close it. However, I don't know which type of close I should vote for.

Is this what I should vote for:

[image: Is this what I should vote for?]

Comment: No MCVE. Images don't constitute an MCVE, just like any arbitrary link doesn't constitute an MCVE

Comment: Needs details or clarity would also be fine.

Comment: _“Questions that contain no code — only images — are generally [closed](//stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for lacking debugging details. Once they are edited to include [a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in_ plain text _form, they can be reopened.”_ — from [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](/a/285557/4642212).

Comment: @MyCar _“MCVE refers to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).”_ — from [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/289905).

Comment: To be clear, "No MCVE" corresponds to "Needs debugging details" in the close dialog.

Comment: Isn't there a more specific duplicate?

Comment: Related (but not good candidates): *[Can we close questions that put most code in an image?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326495/)*, *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/)* (some answers talk about closing, but not in any detail), and *[Propose new reasons to close questions with insufficient information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327622/)* (the question uses SO posts with images as examples)